# Rails: How to generate translation files like django

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-i18n

I am trying to use internationalization in rails. Here i've found that for the command

```
<%= t :hello_world %>
```

I know that Ineed to define **:hello_world** in the file **config/locales/en.yml** like this

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  hello_world: Hello world!
```

What i want to know is as in **django** it **generates translation** files using **makemessages**, is there **any way to do it in rails**? It becomes a tedious task to find and write whole translations.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider checking https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-missing_translations that provides a way to build a yml with missing translations keys while you browse your application.

Wiring it when you run your tests should yielld all missing translations if you have exhaustive coverage.

It doesn't seem as slick as Django's makemessages is, but it's a start.

Comment: hi can you tell me how to add this gem in gemfile, it is not specified in documentation.

Comment: Here it is : gem 'i18n', :git => 'git://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n.git', :ref => '0.5.0'